# Python load dll has error - WindowsError: [Error 4250]

Tags: python, ctypes, dllimport

I was sent a dll file along with a header file and a .lib file, they were compiled with C. But when I try to load the dll file with python using ctypes, I get a error that says "self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 4250]". 
I have put the files sent to me in the python src directory, I also checked the .dll file's dependencies with visual studio's dumpbin command and it says

```
File Type: DLL

Image has the following dependencies:

VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll
ucrtbased.dll
api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-2.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll

Summary

    1000 .00cfg
    1000 .data
    1000 .idata
    3000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    8000 .text
   10000 .textbss
```

The code I used in python was

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
testclib =ctypes.CDLL("Impo.dll")
```

Do I have to link the header files and others in python as well? If so, how should I have done it? or is there something wrong with the dll file itself?

Comment: The error code is `ERROR_NOT_APPCONTAINER`. Apparently the DLL was built for an app container, which python.exe is not.

Comment: Does it mean I can't load it using python?

Comment: Perhaps the DLL was unintentionally linked with th [APPCONTAINER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/appcontainer-windows-store-app) option. Ask the person who sent you the DLL. But the dependency on "api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll" (Windows Runtime) implies otherwise.

Comment: For future reference, Windows error codes are well [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx). You can look them up yourself, which of course should be your very first action when encountering one.

Comment: It looks like it was compiled as a DLL for a Windows Store app, and in debug mode at that.